# What is the value of x? 16-48-98, 32-->x

Tags: mathematics

What's the value of x? ([Original picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDV90.png))

```
4
|
8--8--1
16-48-98
|     |
32--->x
```

I have four possible answer choices: 130, 132, 160, and 260. I'm not sure which one is correct, or if there's another value that could also be correct.

I apologize for not being able to attribute the author of this puzzle as I only found it in a Discord chat (discord.gg/mathematics).

I think the answer is 160, since

> 8 x 1 = 8
>
> 16 x 3 = 48
>
> 32 x 5 = 160

Comment: Could you say which Discord server? Who posted it?

Comment: I can't for the life of me recall the username, but the server is discord.gg/mathematics.